# How does the class loader loads an instance of extended class which is declared inside a method? (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, contextclassloader

I have a class which have util functions and can be invoked on demand.

Steps to Reproduce :

1. TestMainWebApp (this project having Dependency of TestMainImp)
2. TestMainImpl  ( this project implements  TestMainInterface)
3. TestMainInterface

**TestMainWebApp > *TestMainServlet.java***

```
package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.test.util.Util;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestMainServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestMainServlet")
public class TestMainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
         System.out.println("\nCurrent ClassLoader chain: "+JavaEETrainingUtil.getCurrentClassloaderDetail());
         Util prov = new Util();
        // prov.test();
        }
}
```

**TestMainImpl > *Util.java & TLSErrorRedirectListener.java***

```
package com.test.util;
public class Util {
     private final static String CLAZZ = Util.class.getName();
    static {
            System.out.println("Classloading of "+CLAZZ+" in progress..."+JavaEETrainingUtil.getCurrentClassloaderDetail());

     }
        public boolean checkForTLSErrorRedirection(boolean b) {                         
            test.intf.ConfigurationListener listener = new com.listener.TLSErrorRedirectListener();   
            listener.valueChanged("test", "test");
            return true;

        }    

public void test() {  
        System.out.println(" test util");  
    }

}
```

***TLSErrorRedirectionListener.java***

```
package com.listener;
import com.test.util.JavaEETrainingUtil;
public class TLSErrorRedirectListener implements test.intf.ConfigurationListener {
     final static String CLAZZ = TLSErrorRedirectListener.class.getName();
     static {
            System.out.println("Classloading of "+CLAZZ+" in progress..."+JavaEETrainingUtil.getCurrentClassloaderDetail());
     }
    public void valueChanged(String key, String value) {
        switch(key){
        case "test1": 
        default : break;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestMainInterface >*ConfigurationListener.java***

```
package test.intf;
public abstract interface ConfigurationListener
{
  public abstract void valueChanged(String paramString1, String paramString2);
}
```

CASE :

1. TestMainInterface.jar will be in classpath of TestMainImpl.jar (@compiletime only)
2. At RunTime (i wont have TestMainInterface.jar)  and I don't invoke the method "checkForTLSErrorRedirection()" .  i invoke only test() method.
3. But Iam getting , java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/intf/ConfigurationListener
   when i create instance itself.

Can you please help to find out the root cause ?  How does the java loads Class which is declared within a method ?

NOTE : **JavaEETrainingUtil.java**  for debug purpose

```
package noclassdef.example1;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.lang.ClassLoader;

/**
 * JavaEETrainingUtil
 * @author Pierre-Hugues Charbonneau
 *
 */
public class JavaEETrainingUtil {

        /**
         * getCurrentClassloaderDetail
         * @return
         */
        public static String getCurrentClassloaderDetail() {

               StringBuffer classLoaderDetail = new StringBuffer();       
               Stack<ClassLoader> classLoaderStack = new Stack<ClassLoader>();

               ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

               classLoaderDetail.append("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");

               // Build a Stack of the current ClassLoader chain
               while (currentClassLoader != null) {

                       classLoaderStack.push(currentClassLoader);

                       currentClassLoader = currentClassLoader.getParent();
               }

               // Print ClassLoader parent chain
               while(classLoaderStack.size() > 0) {

                       ClassLoader classLoader = classLoaderStack.pop();

                       // Print current                     
                       classLoaderDetail.append(classLoader);

                       if (classLoaderStack.size() > 0) {
                              classLoaderDetail.append("\n--- delegation ---\n");           } else {
                              classLoaderDetail.append(" **Current ClassLoader**");
                       }
               }
               classLoaderDetail.append("\n-----\n");
               return classLoaderDetail.toString();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct.  You should not add the `abstract` keyword to interfaces or their methods.  No need for `public` on interface methods; they are required to be public.

This is correct:

```
package test.intf;
public interface ConfigurationListener {
  void valueChanged(String paramString1, String paramString2);
}
```

Be sure that the `test.intf.ConfigurationListener.class` file appears in your deployment.  If it doesn't, the class loader will never find it.

Comment: Thank you ,  my usecase is , if i call checkForTLSErrorRedirection() API , i will have test.intf.ConfigurationListener.class in my classpath . if i need only test() API , i dont want to have test.intf.ConfigurationListener.class.  But why do i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/intf/ConfigurationListener when i call test() API ? why does the classloader trying to find ConfigurationListener class which is defined only in checkForTLSErrorRedirection() ?

Comment: Iam able to achieve my usecase if i move 
` test.intf.ConfigurationListener listener = new com.listener.TLSErrorRedirectListener();   
    listener.valueChanged("test", "test");` to some other util file . but couldn't find the reason behind it